# Clearing Transforms Doesn't Make Rest Pose (IK problem?)

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I have a problem where my pose position and my Rest Pose position are not the same, even when I have cleared all transforms for the pose position.  It has something to do with the IK bones - perhaps roll settings.  How can I make the pose position look like the rest position?
Here's an GIFF of the resulting problem:
[image: gif]

Comment: it may be because, If the IK bones don't already stick to their controller in Edit mode, then it will make them stick to them as soon as you switch to Pose mode? If it's not the problem, maybe share your armature: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I'm not sure that that's it.  I'll see about sharing my armature tho.

Comment: Here's a question - is it possible to apply the Rest Pose as your current Pose Mode?  This may not be the solution but I'm curious.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible (the opposite is possible though). Please share your file, I'm sure it has to do with the IK or other constraints

Comment: Here is the rig for the project: https://pasteall.org/blend/4b8ae7ab4c724dd994b18974c26edf0a

Comment: I started trying to redo the ik on the armature.  It looks like when I add the pole bones as the poles to the ik modifier to the forearm, it changes the orientation of the elbow as seen in the GIF above.  Why is that, and how can I fix it?  (This is only part of the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you, there's a difference between the *Rest* and *Pose* position of the bones because of the fact that the IK bones will stick to their controller as soon as you switch to *Pose* mode, and if the controller head is not placed exactly where the IK bone's tail is placed, it will make the IK jump. How to fix it?

- First select the IK bone and make all the other ones invisible. Then select its tail and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to put the 3D cursor on the same position.

[image]

- Then unhide everything and this time make only the controller visible. As you see the controller's head is not at the exact same position as the 3D cursor:

[image]

- So press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> in order to put the selection on the 3D cursor:

[image]

- Now when you'll switch from *Rest* to *Pose* they won't be any difference (actually there's still a bit difference because of the target position, you can fix that by making sure that the target is well aligned with the IK.
- As a side note, always bend the elbows and the knees a bit so that Blender knows how to bend it when you switch to *Pose* mode:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I actually already started making a new rig which has been working beautifully, probably because I followed those rules u just mentioned!  Thanks a lot for your help; that is something I'll definitely watch out for in the future!